# Join Records in Linq one column?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, model-view-controller

[image]

I want the output like

```
Test Genre1/
Test Genre2/
Test Genre3/Test genre1               //(Bcoz id 1 as Test Genre1)
Test Genre4/Test genre2               //(Bcoz id 2 as Test Genre2)
Test genre1/Test Test genre3/Genre5   //(Bcoz id 3 as Test Genre3)
```

It should be combination of the `id` and `parent id` in `Linq`.

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Can you please share the code which you have tried?

Comment: I didn't tried yet. I am confusing

Comment: It has to be LINQ?

Comment: Yes. in linq only

Comment: Why, if I may ask?

Comment: Bcoz i have bind this data in dropdownlist . In my mvc project based on some logic

Comment: Dont see why it has to be LINQ only in your described scenario.

Comment: Your output example makes no sense. You order them child to parent in the first four entries and parent to child in the fifth. You also will not be able to do this in a single LINQ query if you want to support an indefinite number of levels. You need recursion for that, which LINQ doesn't provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a recursive function and use that function in your linq. something like this.

```
//Recursive method
 private static string GetParentPath( IEnumerable<Item> items , Item item )
    {
        if (item.ParentId.HasValue)
        {
            return GetParentPath(items, items.First(i => i.Id == item.ParentId)) + "/" + item.GenreName;
        }

        return item.GenreName;
    }



var items = new Item[]
        {
            new Item {Id = 1, GenreName = "Test Genre 1", ParentId = null},
            new Item {Id = 2, GenreName = "Test Genre 2", ParentId = null},
            new Item {Id = 3, GenreName = "Test Genre 3", ParentId = 1},
            new Item {Id = 4, GenreName = "Test Genre 4", ParentId = 2},
            new Item {Id = 5, GenreName = "Test Genre 5", ParentId = 3}
        };



 // Linq query
        var result = from child in items
                  select new { Path = GetParentPath(items, child) };



    //Class used in example
 public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string GenreName { get; set; }

        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a recursive method returning `IEnumerable` defined on the entity class:

```
public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Genre> GetSelfAndAncestors(IEnumerable<Genre> items)
    {
        yield return this;

        if (ParentId.HasValue)
        {
            var parent = items.First(x => x.Id == ParentId.Value);

            foreach (var ancestor in parent.GetSelfAndAncestors(items))
            {
                yield return ancestor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var genres = new[]
{
    new Genre {Id = 1, Name = "Test Genre 1", ParentId = null},
    new Genre {Id = 2, Name = "Test Genre 2", ParentId = null},
    new Genre {Id = 3, Name = "Test Genre 3", ParentId = 1},
    new Genre {Id = 4, Name = "Test Genre 4", ParentId = 2},
    new Genre {Id = 5, Name = "Test Genre 5", ParentId = 3}
};

foreach (var genre in genres)
{
    var path = genre.GetSelfAndAncestors(genres);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("/", path.Select(x => x.Name)));
}
```

If the tree is deep, you might notice a significant performance hit comparing this implementation with a non-`IEnumerable` one.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that with your implementation you could do `var result = String.Join("/",path.Select(x => x.Name))` to get the desired output. The OP Might not know that your `path` result is just an enumerable of `Genre` representing their tree branch.

Comment: all on one line makes it much harder to read. Hope you dont mind i edited it back to 2 simpler lines

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given a method to be called recursively which

1. Adds the name to a string
2. Calls itself recursively with any existing parent

---

```
private static string SelectGenreName(IEnumerable<Genre> all, Genre g)
{
    var s = g.Name + '/';
    if(g.ParentId.HasValue){
        s += SelectGenreName(all, all.Single(x => x.Id == g.ParentId.Value));   
    }
    return s;
}
```

The code to get a sensible result* is quite straightforward:
<sub>* sensible result; Your last example was reversed from the previous 4. The above gives results as per your first four examples. ie `Child/Parent/Grandparent`</sub>

```
var genres = new[]
{
    new Genre {Id = 1, Name = "Test Genre 1", ParentId = null},
    new Genre {Id = 2, Name = "Test Genre 2", ParentId = null},
    new Genre {Id = 3, Name = "Test Genre 3", ParentId = 1},
    new Genre {Id = 4, Name = "Test Genre 4", ParentId = 2},
    new Genre {Id = 5, Name = "Test Genre 5", ParentId = 3}
};

var result = genres.Select(g => SelectGenreName(genres,g));

foreach(var r in result)
    Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/MXQUH43732

Comment: Do you consider this solution ``LINQ only`` as OP mentions in the comments below his question?

Comment: @RandRandom are you asking if this can be executed using EntityFramework (ie, against a db directly) or whether it is pure Linq (aka LinqToObjects)?

Comment: "pure LINQ" (aka LinqToObjects)

Comment: @RandRandom 100% yes. Which part are you unsure about? the fact ive not used the awful `from x select y` syntax and gone for lambdas instead?

Comment: Also thought of a recursive method, but I didnt consider it LINQ only was just wondering, if you had read the comments and you believe your code is LINQ only. What I would interpret as LINQ only is using only the existing methods

Comment: @RandRandom I still have no idea why you think this isnt linq (and why you felt it necessary to post the same comment on every answer!). There is literally no way to answer this without recursion of one type or another

Comment: As I said, I wouldnt see it LINQ ``only`` because you created your own method (``SelectGenreName``). I wouldnt intrepret it, as ``only`` using LINQ.

Comment: About the same comment on every answer, I wanted to know everyones point of view on that topic and not yours alone.

Comment: @RandRandom *every time* you use linq, you "create your own method" - `x.Select(y => y.Foo)` <-- anonymous method. You cant do recursion with an anonymous method like that, you cant answer this question without recursion.

Comment: Good point there, seems like my mind treated the method needed for recursion more special then it actually is.